# Why builder.Use is not working after migrating from net5 to net6?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

After I've changed version of the .NET from 5 to 6, error in `WebStartup.cs` started to appear.

Code looks like this:

```
app.Map("/status", builder =>
{
        builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
           Log.Debug(context.GetRequestLogString());
           context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
           await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
        });
});
```

And the `Use` word is underlined.

And here is the error message I can see for this part of code:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'UseExtensions.Use(IApplicationBuilder, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>)' and 
'UseExtensions.Use(IApplicationBuilder, Func<HttpContext, RequestDelegate, Task>)'
```

What should I change to make this work in net6?

Comment: it just says that it can't match your call to any of the defined extensions. What is the type of the `next`?

Comment: Try adding: `await next(context);` inside the function. Then the call won't be ambiguous .

Answer (score 1):

I've found this issue on the ASP.Net Core repository which solves that exact problem:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32020

Basically, they're saying that we should use `app.Run` instead of `app.Use` when the middleware never calls next, otherwise we will get that compile error.

I haven't tried this myself yet, but I'm guessing it should work. So with your code it would be:

```cs
builder.Run(async (context) =>
        {
           Log.Debug(context.GetRequestLogString());
           context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
           await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
        });
```

EDIT

If you're looking to add middleware to a specific endpoint, you could add a `await next()` at the end of your app.Use(). There surely is a cleaner way to solve this problem but that's my best shot.

Comment: That issue is about `app.Run` and `app.Use`. In this question though the OP is trying to add middleware to a *specific* endpoint, not the application in general.

Comment: Then OP could add a `await next()` line at the end of their app.Use. There is surely a better way to solve this but this is the best workaround I've found so far.